# Why change data in beforeCreated/created/beforeMount can not trigger watch in VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why change data in beforeCreated/created/beforeMount can not trigger watch in VUE?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <titi :namer="parentName"></titi>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    titi: {
      template: "<h1>{{namer}}</h1>",
      props: ["namer"],
      watch: {
        namer: {
          immediate: false,
          handler(val, oldVal) {
            console.log("jackieyin", val);
          }
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log("jackieyin", "mounted");
      }
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      parentName: "jackieyin"
    };
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log(222);
    this.parentName = "sunwukong";
  },
  created() {
    this.parentName = "kewu";
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.parentName = "tangseng";
  },
  mounted() {
    // var that = this;
    // this.parentName = "tyty";
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   that.parentName = "shaseng";
    // }, 500);
  }
};
</script>
```

I try to change data in these lifecycle, but can not trigger the child element props watch. You can try it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watch-inx4z

Comment: by the time `titi` is created, `namer` is already `tangseng` - therefore, there is no change for the `watch` to report

Comment: @Bravo when i change the parentName in mounted method it can trigger the watch,but in beforeMount method it can not trigger.Why?

Comment: because `titi` doesn't even exist before the parent component is *created* - how can a child exist without a parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is behaving as I would expect. If you consider the life cycle sequence below, on the parent the child components only get created *after* `beforeMount` on the parent and before `mounted` on the parent. So, your watch on the child is not going to fire for changes to the prop made in `beforeCreate` or `created` by the parent, because the child does not exist at that point.

- Parent `beforeCreate`
- Parent `created`
- Parent `beforeMount`

  - Child `beforeCreate`

    - Child watcher will fire here *if* `immediate: true`, with the initial value passed
  - Child `created`
  - Child `beforeMount`
  - Child `mounted`
- *Any change to the property here will fire the child watcher from this point*
- Parent `mounted`

In your watcher, you set the value `immediate: false` on the watch. That means, it won't fire when the initial value for the property is set. If you change that to true, you would see the value the parent is setting in `beforeMount` triggers the watch immediately when the child component gets created. Also, if you changed the value again in the parent `mounted` life cycle hook, the watcher in the child will pick that up no matter the value for `immediate`.

Comment: Thank you! I almost understand.But, I still have one question.When i change value in Parent created method,It also fire the watch as the imediate set as true. But the child component is not build now when parent is in created method.How can the child watch method be triggered then?

Comment: Have a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watch-wnd07, open up the console to see the sequence of events. Anything set in the `created` lifecycle hook of the parent does not reach the watch, unless nothing else is set between that and `beforeCreate` on the child. `Immedate:  true` means the watch will fire as soon as the child gets created with the initial value passed to it, so if that happened to have been set in the parent `created` hook, even though child didn't exist at that time, it'll still fire for it if nothing was set afterwards, as it becomes the initial value passed to it.

Comment: Can i ask you one more question.I try to know when computed will be fired.I tried in this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watch-cxsvc, But ,why the computed be fired in parent after beforeMount method not after created method. I read in Vue document(https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) that the computed/data will be attached after created method。

Comment: The computed method is called during the render, because in the template of the parent you have `{{ ptname }}`. Though it is available before then, there isn't any place which calls the `ptname` computed prop in your example prior to the render. The render happens after `beforeMount` which creates the virtual DOM representation of the template, and when that completes and it is mounted to the real DOM, that is when the `mounted` life cycle hook is called.